# How to run a bash code on a certain time and day

Tags: bash, cron, scheduled-tasks, jobs

The code to run a bash code on a certain time is `

```
anycode| at anytime:anytime
```

.
But how would you be able to run a code on a certain time and a certain day (e.g 10:00 on Monday).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cron` to do this. You need to add record like this:

```
0 10 * * 1 /path/to/script
```

0 is for minutes
10 is for hours
first * is for day of month
second * is for month
1 is for day of week (Monday)